# Help/Advice on my UV Map

Tags: uv

I'm super new to Blender and I'm currently going through the process of making a model for Unity, and I've just finished a draft of my low-poly UV Map but I feel like I have way too many seams, but without the seams it becomes super stretched! It's a water cooler and I'm happy with a lot of the seams, but the cup dispenser and cup station are just super messy and I'm struggling to fix it! I've attached photos below and the project can be found [here](https://we.tl/t-PDYwGyQNEo).

I'd love anyone's advice on how it looks so far and where I can improve, thanks!

[image: UVMap][image: Water Cooler]

[image: Water Cooler Angle]

Answer (score 0):

You're absolutely right for GEs you want to keep the seam count als low as possible
It's a bit hard to tell from that angle, but 
[image]

The one with the arrow, you can definetly remove. The one with the circle, I guess there you can save yourself some seams. Just think of the jpg as a piece of paper, if it's possible to cut and then wrap the paper around your model, there will be little to none distortion. That means all the vertical ones along the cylinder are crucial.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Obviously the angle isn't perfect, but I did try remove the seam you mentioned and to clean up the circled part, but it created a lot of stretching unfortunately... :(

Comment: my guess is you're missing a vertical seam between the 2 seams between the upper and lower from the arrow.